# Group by with limit for 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I have this MYSQL query

```
        select * from {$this->table} sc
        join db_sc_profile scp 
        on scp.subcategory_id = sc.subcategory_id
        join db_profile p
        on p.profile_id = scp.profile_id
        where sc.subcategory_id in (" . implode(',', $subcategories) . ")
        and p.profile_id in  (" .implode(',', $profiles) .
        group by p.profile limit ####
```

this query doesn't work with this line `group by p.profile limit ####`. So
i want to group by `p.profile` but limit for `12/count(profiles)`.

Can i do that ? please any help.

NB :  I'm using Codeigniter 2

Comment: 1: Did you try it? 2: You have a syntax error on the second to last line (you don't re-open the double quotes after concatenating the implode).

Comment: Give us a sample of the input and the expected output.

Comment: Yes i know it's work, i modified it just to show you how to add group by and limit . i can explain : i want for example 6 subcategories by profile

Answer (score 0):

Input example

```
  [subcategories] =  Array
(
[0] => 101
[1] => 102
[2] => 103

)

 [profiles] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5
        [1] => 6
    )
```

they are two tables in database linked by a third table

```
profile = [profile_id, profile_name]

subcategory  = [sc_id, sc_name,...]

profile_subcategory = [profile_id, sc_id]
```